# Gmail “suspicious sign-in prevented” message - How to stop it?

Tags: gmail, security, google-account

I am a Spaniard living in China. Recently I have been receiving many alert messages from Google "Preventing myself" from accessing my account. I think because I use a VPN to connect to the internet.

My main problem is that my account is blocked until I go to a Google website to unblock it (most of the times changing my password). I can't count how many passwords I invented last month.

Is there any way to contact Google so they stop the prevention, or any way to disable this precaution alert? I think I prefer taking the risk...

Comment: please check this https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/EMq9NNkjDD0

Answer (score 1):

This works:

On your Gmail mail box look at the bottom right corner and you can see a Details button. Click on it and then on the pop up window change the suspicious warning settings.

Source : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/EMq9NNkjDD0

Comment: That wont prevent google from preventing the suspicious sign in unfortunately. It will mean you aren't notified.

Comment: Details Popup window doesn't have a way of changing the warning settings anymore.

Comment: As of 2021 I don't even see a Details popup in gmail, and no security settings are exposed in the settings interface.

Answer (score 0):

I applied this solution and as a result I obtained this answer:

```
Alert preference: Never show an alert for unusual activity.
```

Which is what I was looking for. For me, it is enough.